# Lookbehind with "not character" ignores match at position 0

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I am trying to achieve a regex to select `(%?[fFsmhd]){1,}` preceded by `+` and not by `\+`.

My first option was `(?<=[^\\]\+)(%?[fFsmhd]){1,}` which seems to work except that the position 1 is never matched.

Test:

```
+fFsmhd (problem here, does not match)
+fFsmhd (matches)
```

A workaround I found to this problem is to replace the `[^\\]` for a nested negated lookbehind ending up with this disgusting thing: `(?<=(?<!\\)\+)(%?[fFsmhd]){1,}`

Test:

```
+fFsmhd (matches)
+fFsmhd (matches)
```

Is there any better way to achieve this without nest lookbehinds to do a simple `[^\\]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without lookarounds it is not quite possible to do what you want. Actually, you have a flaw in the pattern: if there is a literal `\` before `+`, it won't get matched. You need to account for any amount of double backslashes:

```cs
(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\+)(%?[fFsmhd])+
```

See this [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3C!%5C%5C%29%28%3F%3A%5C%5C%7B2%7D%29*%5C%2B%29%28%25%3F%5BfFsmhd%5D%29%2B&i=%2BfFsmhd%20%28problem%20here%2C%20does%20not%20match%29%0D%0A%2BfFsmhd%20%28matches%29).

The `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\+)` lookbehind requires a `+` immediately on the left that is not immediately preceded with `\` and then any amount of double backslashes.

Comment: Woah, such a good correction, thank you very much.
I don't get what (?:\\{2}) does, but I am sure with a bit of Googling I can get it easy.

Comment: @Pakoco `(?:\\{2})*` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) that matches two backslashes zero or more times.  Note you may achieve what you want using one lookaround and a capturing group: `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\+((?:%?[fFsmhd])+)`. The [text you need](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5c%5c%7b2%7d%29*%5c%2b%28%28%3f%3a%25%3f%5bfFsmhd%5d%29%2b%29&i=%2bfFsmhd+%2bfFsmhd++%5c%5c%5c%2bfFsmhd++%5c%5c%2bfFsmhd++%5c%2bfFsmhd+) is in Group 1.